# Why doesn't the compiler give a conflicting error?

Tags: c, variables, gcc, structure, c11

In following code, I have declared a structure member variable as a same name of structure name.

```
struct st 
{     
    int st;
};

int main()
{
   struct st t;
   t.st = 7;
   return 0;
}
```

I wonder, it's working fine on **GCC** compiler and doesn't give a conflict error.

So,

- How does the compiler know structure name and variable name?
- What mechanism compiler internally use?

Comment: What does `main()` return?

Comment: Variables and structure names are different entities for any C compiler starting from KnR. Sort of different namespaces, if you wish. So it's perfectly normal.

Comment: `struct` tells the compiler to tokenize the following `st` as a struct with value `st`. Similarly, the member `int st` is declared as an `int` variable with name `st`. Their usages are orthogonal so the compiler can't possibly get confused during lexical analysis.

Comment: There is no place where the identifier `st` could be ambiguous. Depending on the context, it can be either a struct name or a field name but never both.

Comment: The [old way](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4970087/17034) was too painful.  So they fixed it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it's valid. The struct tag and the struct members are in different namespace.

[C11, 6.2.3 Name spaces of identifiers](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.3):

> If more than one declaration of a particular identifier is visible at any point in a translation unit, the syntactic context disambiguates uses that refer to different entities. Thus, there are separate name spaces for various categories of identifiers, as follows:
>
> - label names (disambiguated by the syntax of the label declaration and use);
> - the tags of structures, unions, and enumerations (disambiguated by following any32) of the keywords struct, union, or enum);
> - the members of structures or unions; each structure or union has a separate name space for its members (disambiguated by the type of the expression used to access the member via the . or -> operator);
> - all other identifiers, called ordinary identifiers (declared in ordinary declarators or as enumeration constants).

Answer (score 3):

The name of the structure type is `struct st`. Not just `st`, so there's no conflict at all.