# What does "e_lfanew" mean in the DOS header for the PE format?

Tags: windows, portable-executable

In the `IMAGE_DOS_HEADER` for the PE (Windows executable) format there is a field known as `e_lfanew`, it serves a very important role in that it points to the actual PE header data.

My question is, what does "e_lfanew" actually stand for? what does it mean? It's so cryptic.

EDIT: I'm **NOT** asking what it does, i know what it does, i want to know what the letters in `e_lfanew` actually stand for, why was it given that name?

Comment: @i486 i'm not asking what it does, i know what it does, i want to know what the letters in `e_lfanew` actually stand for, why was it given that name?

Comment: From WinNT.h:  `LONG  e_lfanew;   // File address of new exe header`.  The `e_` prefix helped deal with [old K&R compilers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4970087/what-does-the-s-mean-in-the-structure) that did not yet keep structure members in its own symbol table.  The `l` is system Hungarian for LONG.  You can guess fanew.  What are you going to do differently now that you know?

Comment: @HansPassant thanks! I guess i'll get a beer to celebrate :) It was itching my curiosity!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

My interpretation would be that it's the **l**ogical **f**ile **a**ddress for the [**New** Executable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Executable) header.

Mainly based on the comment in this P/Invoke C# definition of the [IMAGE_DOS_HEADER](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Structures.IMAGE_DOS_HEADER) struct:

> ```
> public Int32 e_lfanew;      // File address of new exe header
> ```

And a comment by [@Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47711282/what-does-e-lfanew-mean-in-the-dos-header-for-the-pe-format/47711673?noredirect=1#comment82385254_47711282):

> The `e_` prefix helped deal with [old K&R compilers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4970087/what-does-the-s-mean-in-the-structure) that did not yet keep structure members in its own symbol table.

And a later comment here by [@Simon Kissane](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2147204/simon-kissane):

> Inside the `IMAGE_DOS_HEADER` there are two fields starting with `e_lfa`:
>
> - `WORD   e_lfarlc; // File address of relocation table`
> - `LONG   e_lfanew; // File address of new exe header`

The "lfa" would appear to mean "logical file address", meaning the offset relative to the start of the executable file.

Comment: This is a good guess, but I don't think the `long` part is right. Inside `IMAGE_DOS_HEADER` there are two fields starting with `e_lfa`: `WORD e_lfarlc; // File address of relocation table` and `LONG e_lfanew; // File address of new exe header`. `e_lfanew` is a `LONG` (32-bit) but `e_lfarlc` is a `WORD` (16-bit, a `short`). Obviously `fa` means "file address", but I doubt the `l` is for "long". I believe "lfa" is actually "logical file address", which is old term for the offset from start of file. In the modern PE format, the same idea is called the RVA (relative virtual address)