# Why the AF_INET, AF_INET6 parameters are assigned to variables of int type?

Tags: c, struct, network-programming

I understand that this must be an extremely noob question. I've started reading a book on network programming & I came to see that AF_INET, AF_INET6 are being assigned to variables of int type. I just want to know how they yield int values.

Comment: Because they are macros, which are expanded by the preprocessor to integer literals.

Comment: What else would they be? What else did you expect? You *do* know about symbolic constants and preprocessor macros?

Comment: Just an historical artifact, it should have been an enum type.  But early K&R compilers did not yet have support for them.  Sockets are about 1983, being able to count on enum types was 1989.  Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/4970260/17034